# WebGL and the power of two image size

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to use WebGL to make a little 3D gallery of Flickr photo streams. It looks like WebGL only allows square images that's dimensions are a power of two to be used as textures. I need to be able to display images of any proportion and dimension. I can see that if I copy the image data into another image that is the nearest square dimension and then use texture coordinates to make it display right. The problem is, and correct me if I am wrong, that I can't do that image manipulation in JavaScript and would need a server running ASP.NET, Java or something like that to do the processing for me before WebGL could get its hands on it.

Is there a way of using arbitrarily sized images in WebGL and JavaScript without the need for a server to act as a middle man image processor?

Answer (score 18):

I have no problem with npot textures (FF & chrome) provided that you execute:

```
texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, LINEAR);
texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, LINEAR);
texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_WRAP_S, CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
texParameteri(TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_WRAP_T, CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Comment: http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/WebGL_and_OpenGL_Differences#Non-Power_of_Two_Texture_Support states you can't have repeating non power of 2 textures, but CLAMP_TO_EDGE is allowed.

Answer (score 10):

[This page](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/WebGL_and_OpenGL_Differences#Non-Power_of_Two_Texture_Support) nicely sums up the situation (and more or less restates what the other answerers here have already said).  Basically, WebGL does not support NPOT textures with mipmapping and/or repeats.  And if you can't get away without those modes, the texture can be resized in a 2D canvas.  And the page includes some handy code for canvas resizing.

**Update:** WebGL2, the next version of WebGL, [supports NPOT textures](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#4.1.3).

Answer (score 4):

Reference provided by @EnabrenTane is very helpful. [Non-Power of Two Texture Support](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/WebGL_and_OpenGL_Differences#Non-Power_of_Two_Texture_Support)

> While OpenGL 2.0 and later for the desktop offer full support for
>   non-power-of-two (NPOT) textures, OpenGL ES 2.0 and WebGL have only
>   limited NPOT support. The restrictions are defined in Sections 3.8.2,
>   "Shader Execution", and 3.7.11, "Mipmap Generation", of the OpenGL ES
>   2.0 specification, and are summarized here:
>
> - generateMipmap(target) generates an INVALID_OPERATION error if the level 0 image of the texture currently bound to target has an NPOT
>     width or height.
> - Sampling an NPOT texture in a shader will produce the RGBA color (0, 0, 0, 1) if:
>
>   - The minification filter is set to anything but NEAREST or LINEAR: in other words, if it uses one of the mipmapped filters.
>   - The repeat mode is set to anything but CLAMP_TO_EDGE; repeating NPOT textures are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the low-level details well enough to completely answer your question, but here are some things I found:

[This post](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=2606) is not encouraging:

> Texture handling has been updated in
>   Minefield so that [it] better matches
>   the specification; previously it was
>   quite forgiving [...] and allowed you
>   to use textures that weren’t really
>   valid from a WebGL viewpoint. Now it
>   doesn’t [...] you’ll see an error
>   message saying “A texture is going to
>   be rendered as if it were black, as
>   per the OpenGL ES 2.0.24 spec section
>   3.8.2, because it is a 2D texture, with a minification filter not
>   requiring a mipmap, with its width or
>   height not a power of two, and with a
>   wrap mode different from
>   CLAMP_TO_EDGE.”

I don't know if those extra conditions apply to your app. See also the [OpenGL ES spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.24.pdf).

[This thread](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/archives/1001/msg00158.html) goes fairly in-depth on support for "NPOT":

> > > > OpenGL supports NPOT textures in two ways. The first is called "Rectangle
> > > >         Textures" (RT), which can be any size, but can't be repeating, mip-mapped or
> > > >         have borders. And rather than using 0-1 texture coordinates, they use 0-w,
> > > >         0-h. OpenGL Also supports true NPOT textures, which have similar constraints
> > > >         to RT, but which use the normal 0-1 texture coordinates.
> > > >
> > > > The issue is that some older hardware (and when I say "older" I mean
> > > >         hardware from 2005) only supports RT, not true NPOT. It's not possible to
> > > >         emulate NPOT when you just have RT support because in GLSL you use a
> > > >         different sampler for RT (sampler2DRect vs sampler2D).
> > > >
> > > > OpenGL ES only supports NPOT, not RT.

...

> > > A WebGL implementation can scale up NPOT texture data to the next
> > >       highest power of two dimension during texImage2D and texSubImage2D
> > >       calls. This wouldn't involve any API changes. O3D does this in some
> > >       cases as proof that the technique can work without the end user
> > >       knowing. I think it would be a bad idea to expose rectangular textures
> > >       in the WebGL API; they are definitely not the path forward.

So, take that FWIW...

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to resize using 2d canvas and use that as a texture.